# HttpServletRequest and getHeader(): How to handle case insensitive headers properly?

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

Since I discovered that HTTP headers are case-insensive according to the RFC, i was wondering how I can access HTTP headers in a case-insensitive way with Servlets. There is a #getHeader(String) method to obtain a header but it turned out that this method treats the header fields case sensitive.

Is there a "case insensitive" way to get header fields ? Or do i have to iterate over all the header fields to find the header field I was looking for ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which servlet container are you using? The [docs for `getHeader(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-) state:

> The header name is case insensitive.

so it sounds like a bug in the container you're using.

Comment: Actually, its Jetty 5. I'll investigate this issue, thank for pointing me to the Java EE documentation... ;-)

Comment: I think Jetty might be up to version 6 (or 7?), you might want to take a look at upgrading.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but I just wanted to note that Tomcat 7.0.39 also returns case sensitive headers.

Comment: @bmauter: Do you mean that if you request `CONTENT-TYPE` it won't give you the value for `Content-Type`? That sounds broken...

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct.  I asked for "Authorization" and got nothing when iOS sent "authorization".  I can reproduce this at will.

Comment: @bmauter: Odd. I'd file a bug against Tomcat (or see if there's an existing one). It's clearly violating the spec, judging by your description.

Comment: @JonSkeet Nevermind, it looks like I am an idiot.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, Tomcat 8.0.9 is doing this way: the headers are all lowercase. :((

Comment: same as @JonSkeet , getHeader("Authorization") is failing to recognize header "authorization", and this is on tomcat8. When i change the actual header to "Authorization" then it works.

Answer (score 3):

tomcat 8.0.24 impl of getHeader delegates to 'org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders' which eventually calls this method below which in turn does case insensitive check

```
313  public MessageBytes getValue(String name) {
```