# Rest - how get IP address of caller

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I am writing a Java Rest Web Service and need the caller's IP Address. I thought I saw this in the cookie once but now I don't see it. Is there a consistent place to get this information?

I saw one example of using an "OperationalContext" to get it but that was not in java.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you need to add Java tags to gain an audience - this is not really REST related

Comment: Maybe not directly Rest related, but certainly web services related (which I don't know much about either), isn't it?  Wouldn't it be a rest/web service concern to know the IP address of the web client that envoke your service?

Comment: First question, how are you creating your RESTful application? With Servlets, Some library, etc?

Comment: If you're trying to use the IP as a unique identifier you're in for a world of hurt if some of your users come from behind a NAT router.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can get the IP through the request object.

If I'm not mistaken, `request.getRemoteAddr()` or so.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't have a request object.  This is a JAX-RS Restful Web service.  I do have access to a Request context object, but that does not have a getRemoteAddr() method and seems to be related to "conditional Gets"... whatever those are.

Comment: Hm.. can't you do something like   @Context HttpServletRequest request and then use this object request.getRemoteAddr() ?

Answer (score 43):

Inject a [HttpServletRequest](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) into your Rest Service as such:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@GET
@Path("/yourservice")
@Produces("text/xml")
public String activate(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@Context SecurityContext context){

   String ipAddressRequestCameFrom = requestContext.getRemoteAddr();
   // header name is case insensitive
   String xForwardedForIP = req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");

   // if xForwardedForIP is populated use it, else return ipAddressRequestCameFrom 
   String ip = xForwardedForIP != null ? xForwardedForIP : ipAddressRequestCameFrom;
   System.out.println("IP is "+ip);


   // get the host name the client contacted. If the header `Host` is populated the `Host` header is automatically returned.
   // An AWS ALB populated the Host header for you.
   String hostNameRequestCameFrom = req.getServerName();
   System.out.println("Host is "+hostNameRequestCameFrom);

   
   //Also if security is enabled
   Principal principal = context.getUserPrincipal();
   String userName = principal.getName();

}
```

As [@Hemant Nagpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557143/hemant-nagpal) mentions, you can also check the [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header to determine the real source if a load balancer inserts this into the request.
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379691/338249), the [getHeader()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-) call is case insensitive.

You can also get the servername that the client contacted. This is either the DNS name or the value set in the [Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header with an OSI layer 7 load balancer can populate.

**1. Example: no headers are populated**

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

returns

```
IP is 127.0.0.1
Host is 127.0.0.1
```

**2. Example: X-Forwarded-For and Host headers are populated**

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" --header "Host: bla.bla.com:8443" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

returns

```
IP is 1.2.3.4
Host is bla.bla.com
```

Comment: `requestContext.getRemoteAddr()` will suffice (without `toString()`)

Comment: `requestContext.getRemoteAddr()` will give you ip address of the apigateway if you are using that. Rather you can use code like :


  `String remoteAddr = null;
   remoteAddr = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
   if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
    remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
   } else {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(remoteAddr,",");
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
     remoteAddr = tokenizer.nextToken();
     break;
    }
   }`

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
@WebService
public class YourService {

   @Resource
   WebServiceContext webServiceContext; 

   @WebMethod 
   public String myMethod() { 

      MessageContext messageContext = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) messageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
      String callerIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

      System.out.println("Caller IP = " + callerIpAddress); 

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are making your "web service" with servlets, the rather simple method call `.getRemoteAddr()` on the request object will give you the callers IP address.

Comment: Not servlets, but Restful Web Services (different, right?).. and I don't have an object that has a getremoteAddr() method.

Answer (score 1):

*If your application is running on a webserver that is located behind a reverse proxy or load balancer, then that proxy can be configured to inject the requested IP address in a request header. Different reverse proxies can inject different headers. Consult the documentation for your proxy server. We listed a couple of the most used in our example below but this is by no means a complete list.
When your client uses a (forward) proxy, then it might insert headers to say what the client IP addres is. Or it might not. And the IP address inserded here might be incorrect.
This means that the value you get by calling request.getRemoteAddr() is the IP address of the immediate upstream source of the request.
As we said, there are many headers for different proxies in use, but x-forwareded-for is most likely to be inserted by a proxy.
As a last note, even if you get an IP address either from the header or from request.getRemoteAddr() it is not guarenteed to be the client IP address. e.g.: if your proxy does not include the IP address of the client then you’ll get the IP address of the proxy or load balancer. If your client works on a private network and connect to the internet via a NAT gateway, then the IP address in the HTTP request will be an address of the NAT server. Or even for a hacker it is quite easy to inject a header with a different IP address. So this means that you cannot reliably find out the IP address of the system that the request originated from.*

```
 private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = { 
        "X-Forwarded-For",
        "Proxy-Client-IP",
        "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_VIA",
        "REMOTE_ADDR" };

    public static String getClientIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
            String ip = request.getHeader(header);
            if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**To get the IP address of an API, you can follow these steps:**

1. Determine the API endpoint: First, you need to know the domain or URL of the API you want to access. For example, if the API is located at `https://abc.example.com`, this is the endpoint you'll be working with.
2. Use Command Prompt/Terminal (Windows/Linux/macOS): Open a command prompt or terminal on your computer.
3. Ping the API endpoint: To get the IP address of the API, you can use the `ping` command followed by the API domain. This will send a small packet to the server and display the IP address it resolves to.

   For example, in Windows/Linux/macOS:

   ```
   ping abc.example.com
   ```
4. Use NSLOOKUP (Windows) or DIG (Linux/macOS) command (optional): If you need more detailed information or if the API domain has multiple IP addresses (for load balancing or redundancy purposes), you can use `nslookup` (Windows) or `dig` (Linux/macOS) command.

   For example, in Windows:

   ```
   nslookup abc.example.com
   ```

   In Linux/macOS:

   ```
   dig abc.example.com
   ```
5. Resolve DNS records (optional): If the API endpoint is behind a domain name, the IP address may change over time due to DNS (Domain Name System) configurations. In this case, you can use online tools or command-line utilities like `nslookup` (Windows) or `dig` (Linux/macOS) with specific options to query the DNS records.

Please note that the IP address you obtain using these methods might change over time due to DNS configurations or load balancing mechanisms used by the API provider. If you need a more reliable way to access the API, it's better to use the domain name directly rather than hardcoding the IP address.