# How to get Remote / Client IP address using RESTful web service in java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-authentication

I have written Rest web service in my project.The web service call may come from different machine.so i need to find out the IP address through REST webservice.

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825084/rest-how-get-ip-address-of-caller) **request.getRemoteAddr()** to use this.

But i cant use getRemoteAddr(). Because my request and response are xml format.

I have used post method in REST service.Tomcat server.I have send request as xml format.

How can i get the IP address?

Comment: can you tell what technology/framework you are using ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming you are using JAX-RS:

```
@GET
Produces("application/xlm")
public String getData(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
   String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

The `@Context` annotation allows you to inject instances of

- javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,
- javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,
- javax.ws.rs.core.Request,
- javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest,
- javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse,
- javax.servlet.ServletConfig,
- javax.servlet.ServletContext, and
- javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext objects.

Comment: This will not give me my public ip if i am hitting from my own system

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the format (or content type) of your request (in this case xml)
The IP address is supplied with your request through which the xml payload (request) is submitted.
Hence, checking with your Request is the best way.

Comment: your request data (xml) is always wrapped in HTTP Request

Answer (score 0):

Even if your request is in xml/json format, you will get Remote/client machine address using `request.getRemoteAddr();` because IP Address lies in [HTTP Request header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_headers).

Comment: I cant get the getRemoteAddr() through xml request object.