# Obtain the request in Resteasy JAX-RS method

Tags: java, rest, httprequest, jax-rs

I have a Jax-Rs service that I run with Resteasy, and in the implementation of the methods I want to access the request data. I know of the existence of the [@Context](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2486) annotation but this requires me to modify the service interface which is not practical (or even possible with Java Jax-Rs clients) that use the same interface for client proxy creation.

So to make it cleaner, I have this interface which I can't modify.

```
@POST
@Path("/ping")
@Consumes({ javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String ping();
```

And in the implementation I want to do something like this (kind of pseudo code)

```
@Override
public String ping() {
    String client = SomeContextAccessor.getRequest().getRemoteAddress());

    //Use the request info

    return "a nice string";
}
```

I know there are some classes with static methods that allow me to do this but can't find info about those.

Comment: According to [the javadoc](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html), `@Context` has `
@Target(value={PARAMETER,METHOD,FIELD}`. So you could try using `@Context` annotation with a field, and retrieving your data from that field in the handler method. This might allow you to access the context without the need to change any methods' signatures.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help. I can't see any methods that would return the actual HTTP request for me. I guess @Context is not what I'm looking for. Need to investigate. But at the same time, the question still stands.

Comment: There is a fixed set of objects you can inject using `@Context`: `Application`, `UriInfo`, `HttpHeaders`, `Request`, `SecurityContext` and `Providers`. Maybe one of this has what you are looking for. What exactly do you wanna know about the HTTP request?

Comment: @rubenlop88 The actual request, as the example shows: remote address, headers, whatever. All the context related stuff is static content, unfortunately. I have used the API I'm asking for but it was a long time ago and I have no clue what I have to tell Google to tell me the secret.

Comment: @allprog My list was incomplete, I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14255549/1415153 with a complete list of classes you can inject using `@Context`. My list is from the JAX-RS specification and javadocs but the Jersey and RESTEasy implementations also allow you to inject for example a `javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest` from wich you can get the remote IP address.

Comment: @rubenlop88 Thank you! In the mean time I found the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is a single line:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpServletRequest.class)
```

I don't know if injecting this in a field is possible. Method level injection does not work either as I'm using Java clients with the same interface definition. Adding context parameters to a method would screw up this scheme.

Anyway, it works great for me.

Comment: Injection results in singletons? Since when? Maybe the @Application scope.
```@GET
@Path("{foo}")
public void getFoo(@Context HttpServletResponse response, ...)```

Comment: More, your way is RestEasy specific. Injection is standardized.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my oversight regarging the singleton. Fixed. However, I think you did not read my comment thoroughly. I had to use the same API for both the client and the server. That is, the interface must remain the same, the signature cannot change. (This is due to some architectural decisions we made.) The question's title explicitly targeted Resteasy. Otherwise, if you have an answer, you can post it.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Still you can @Inject Request, or parts of it, for instance [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) in the implementation, would that work? See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html)

Comment: Could you formulate your proposal in an answer? I don't clearly see where I could inject. Given the interface is untouchable, only fields remain, if I'm correct.