# JBoss resteasy-jaxrs-3.12.1 undertow.core-2.1.3 -- HttpServletRequest null

Tags: servlets, jboss, request, resteasy, undertow

Dear JBoss RESTEasy gurus --

I followed

1. [Resteasy 3 @Context HttpServletRequest always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311703/resteasy-3-context-httpservletrequest-always-null)
2. [Obtain the request in Resteasy JAX-RS method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892223/obtain-the-request-in-resteasy-jax-rs-method)

But I am always getting HttpServletRequest null

Having a) org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final
b) io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final
c) Jdk 15

Here is my code snippet:

```
@Path("{p_uri}/login-actions")
public LActionsService getLActionsService(@Context HttpServletRequest rqst, final @PathParam("p_uri") String name) {
        
        
ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().injectProperties(service);
        
   
//Also tried 
rqst = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().getContextData(HttpServletRequest.class);
      
if(rqst == null ) {
    System.out.println("parameter request is null"); 
        
    // do_somethingelse_with rqst
    
    return service;
}
```

Error dump:

```
RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest 04:44:36,744 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)     
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:77)
```

Any pointers highly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are you using these in a container like WildFly?

Comment: Yes, James ; pure redhat application that includes wildfly, undertow and of course jboss-resteasy -- any further direction? All I am looking for is extracting httpservletrequest in the above, that allows me to do other useful stuff.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an `@GET` or `@POST` annotation on the method? Are you by chance including RESTEasy in your deployment?

Comment: On some methods, 'do have at_Get and at_Post, on others 'have at_Path.  I am aware that only org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs is throwing the error  RESTEASY003880. Anything I can test or follow an example code?

Comment: I just created a simple resource with one method and it worked for me. `@Path("context") @GET public Response checkContext(@Context HttpServletRequest request) { return Response.ok(String.valueOf(request)).build();}`

Comment: Thanks James. I now confirm that parameter based context injection works. After debugging, it tuned out that 'had two conflicting Javax.servlet jars for this module. Once I removed that, it all started working. Not sure how I accept your comment as answer, but yes. Also, really didn't need at_GET and at_POST for the functions eg checkContext. But thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.