# How to get the I.P. Address of client that is hitting your webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

The title pretty much says it all, I have written a REST webservice in Java using JAX-RS and Jersey, and I would like to extract the I.P. address of the client that hits it in my code. If I have a class like this:

```
@Path("/service")
public class Service {

    @GET
    public void doAction () {

        // ...

    }

}
```

What do I do from there?

P.s. I'm **not** asking for debugging help, I'm asking how I can retrieve the IP address of the client that connects to my web service. @ANyarThar provided a good answer.

Comment: Can you make ipAddress argument mandatory in your REST URL?

Comment: You mean ask the client to explicitly enter their IP address? Nope... sadly not

Comment: Not sure for Jersey, but in Spring MVC you can pass the HTTP request as a method parameter.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254999/how-to-get-remote-client-ip-address-using-restful-web-service-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How `@Context HttpServletRequest` as argument in your method,

```
@GET
public void doAction (@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    //then get ip address
    String ipAddress = req.getRemoteHost();
}
```