# How to find both user are same/not?

Tags: javascript, android, unique

I new to Dev World(if i am wrong correct me), and i have to work with two different platforms,
1.Android
2. Web

so, If the same user can use my Androd App as well as my site (throught his/her mobile phones)Now how to find 
both users are same or not using PHP/JAVA/JS. Is there any unique value to find the particular user.

Note: My both projects does not contains the login forms, because using that we cannot check both usernames same/not.

Comment: You must have to get some detail from the user and that way you can check their uniqueness.

Comment: At server side create something that stores list of unique users, i.e. it can be  User's identity number or anything you know is unique , upon interacting with the app you can check from the list that new user is already there or not, through this you can find out !

Comment: @NigamPatro Thanks , but without user details any other possibilities?

Comment: @Moorthy If I am accessing the application from my mobile and accessing the same from my PC. Then there is no way to compare the uniqueness.

Comment: @SaraTirmizi i think its not working because how to assign the unique value to particular users???

Comment: @Moorthy if there is no login, what do you mean by USER?

Comment: @NigamPatro ofc, but now focus on mobile only

Comment: @mastermind it  measn who are consuming my services . .

Comment: **@Moorthy so, If the same user can use my Androd App as well as my site (throught his/her mobile phones)Now how to find both users are same or not using PHP/JAVA/JS. Is there any unique value to find the particular user.**
what do you mean by same user? Since I am a user I have 1 desktop 1 laptop and 2 cell phones .. and without any login information how will I identify who am I?

Comment: Do you want that ur application see the face off user and identify on both(mobile and web) side user is same?? :)

Comment: @Moorthy from my mobile you can pass the device uuid to the API. And every time you can check with this uuid. If that is already there then give the data of the user.

Comment: @SaraTirmizi i focus on mobile only its does not matter about laps and PC

Comment: @mastermind NOOOO

Comment: @NigamPatro okay but how to find which ID is your's ???

Comment: @Moorthy if there is no LOGIN then only from 1 thing u can identify is IP of the user (which can also same for two different users), but u can assume that if SINGLE IP using ur SERVICE from mobile and web is a single user

Comment: @Moorthy **which ID** mean?

Comment: @mastermind you are right but from browsers we can not access or find the IP address . i hope you, you know that.

Comment: @NigamPatro UUID . .

Comment: @Moorthy its possible on ur server side where u receive the call (whose is the caller)

Comment: @Moorthy For every device, there is unique UUID. So, you can get the UUID of the current device and pass to API.

Comment: @mastermind HOW??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address

Comment: again this not 100% correct way to identify the USER

Comment: @NigamPatro UUID from browser is possible??? incase if the user use my site through web browsers means? how to get UUID?

Comment: @mastermind yes its not 100% right

Comment: FOR JAVA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254999/how-to-get-remote-client-ip-address-using-restful-web-service-in-java

Comment: @Moorthy I am talking about the android application. If not needed from the browser then you can save some cookie or session in the Android browser and you can check whether the same user or not. Otherwise, as per mastermind response, you can check the IP address.

Comment: BUT THIS IS THE ONLY POSSIBLE WAY (if u do have login)

Comment: @mastermind yes we can get the ip using java its not pblm but how to check if the particular user or not

Comment: @NigamPatro for cookie or session need to have some login form

Comment: @mastermind Ok.

Comment: @Moorthy LOLZ not possible (Use Apple Face ID)

Comment: @NigamPatro i dont how its 100% working right way, but one thing is right we can not access IP using browser and we can not access cookies/session from any other app outside of browser.

Comment: @Moorthy **@mastermind yes we can get the ip using java its not pblm but how to check if the particular user or not** What is your requirement

Comment: @NigamPatro yes we can not check is same user or not using IP. my requirement is to check the users are same or not when using mobile app and mob browser

Comment: for Requirement -1, but interested to know the solution (although which is not possible), else it could be a privacy breach solution

Comment: @mastermind, and NigamPatro yes i think its not possible

Answer (score 0):

Identifying User without any identification mechanism(Login Form or else)

**NOT POSSIBLE**

Comment: after lot of research i get this https://www.javapoly.com/ and when i try to apply only working in FF not other browsers and also not get IP can u plz check in your enviroment